# Не получается написать SQL-запросы

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]База данных состоит из 3-х таблиц:

- `users` - содержит пользователей сайта;
- `posts` - содержит публикации пользователей сайта. связана с users, для определения к какому пользователю относится публикация;
- `comments` - содержит комментарии к публикациям пользователей.  связана с posts, для определения к какой публикации относится комментарий и связь с users для определения, какому пользователю принадлежит комментарий;

Помогите написать запросы:

- пользователей, у которых есть публикации, но в которых не оставили ни одного комментария;
- пользователей, которые написали более одного комментария в одной и той же публикации;
- пользователи у которых нет ни публикация, ни комментариев.

Comment: Для реализации запросов нужна еще структура этих таблиц

Comment: И после описания структуры напишите примерные запросы которые у вас получились. На этом сайте не выполняют работу за других, а помогают с вопросами, возникшими во время самостоятельной работы ...

Comment: не видно попыток решения

Comment: Похоже, вы забыли добавить код запросов, который вы сами  пытались написать и в котором у вас что-то не получилось. Рекомендую добавить, а то без него вопрос выглядит так, как будто вы хотите, чтобы за вас всё сделали. Минусы на вопросе именно по этой причине.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть имеется следующая структура таблиц

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE posts (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
);

CREATE TABLE comments (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  post_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Тогда для извлечения пользователей, у которых есть публикации, но в которых не оставили ни одного комментария можно воспользоваться следующим запросом:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT u.name
FROM
  posts AS p
LEFT JOIN
  comments AS c
ON
  p.id = c.post_id
LEFT JOIN
  users AS u
ON
  p.user_id = u.id
WHERE
  c.post_id IS NULL
```

Для извлечения пользователей, которые написали более одного комментария в одной и той же публикации можно воспользоваться следующим запросом:

```
SELECT
  p.id AS post_id,
  u.name,
  COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
  posts AS p
JOIN
  comments AS c
ON
  p.id = c.post_id
LEFT JOIN
  users AS u
ON
  p.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY
  p.id, u.id
HAVING
  total > 1
```

Для извлечения пользователи у которых нет ни публикация, ни комментариев можно воспользоваться следующим запросом:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT u.name AS name
FROM
  users AS u
LEFT JOIN
  comments AS c
ON
  u.id = c.user_id
LEFT JOIN
  posts AS p
ON
  u.id = p.user_id
WHERE
  c.user_id IS NULL AND
  p.user_id IS NULL
```